# Thunderbird tasks api

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, todoist, thunderbird-webextensions, thunderbird-lightning

Is there a way to hook into the tasks in Thunderbird as you can do with other parts of the application by addon/webextension?

As far, as I understand it, tasks are part of the calender, which, in return, belongs to the lightning addon - is that, why tasks are not covered by the Thunderbird developer documentation?

If this approach is not possible, here is, what I'm trying to achieve: I want to sync my todoist tasks with my Thunderbird tasks. Todoist only natively offers to sync those with due date but these are imported as calendar events which is not useful for me since many tasks don't have a due date.

The only extension capable of syncing is the one for Google tasks, yet, I wasn't able to get my hands on its source code to maybe get an idea on how they've done it.